# button setImage in android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I have the following part implemented in `iOS.Xamarin`; however I would like to know the equilavent of the following in `android.xamarin`.

```
button.SetImage (selectedImage, UIControlState.Selected);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has an [ImageButton](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.ImageButton/) class that you can use.  It inherits several [SetImage*](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.ImageView/) methods from ImageView that you can use to set the image in code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. I wonder `ImageButton` class has anything similar to `UIControlState.Normal` ?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the docs for ImageButton that I linked to , it discusses handling the different states.

Comment: But it gives an example in xml, I would like to know is there any example in programmatically done in C#?